# How do I find nth IP of the given subnet?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

For example: given subnet 10.10.0.0/16 , if I have to find 1000th ip of given subnet range?

Comment: You can use 1 to 255, so 256+256+256+256 = 1024, we then need to subtract 24 - So 10.10.3.232 is the 1000th IP address.. (because 256+256+256+256 = 10.10.4.0 minus 24 = 10.10.3.232)

Answer (score 0):

So you can have total available IP address equal to 2^16 = 65536 (considering 16 bits available). Now, to find your 1000 IP address, you can use your 10 least significant bits. So it would be like 10.10.00000011.11101000/16 that would be equal to 10.10.3.232/16.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the ip address to binary:

   00001010.00001010.00000000.00000000
2. Convert the mask to binary:

   11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000

*(The first 16 bits are masked. This gives us the last 16 bits for addresses.)*

3. The first address 10.10.0.0 will be the subnet address
4. The first 255 addresses will be 10.10.0.1 - 10.10.0.255
5. The second 256 addresses will be 10.0.1.0 - 10.10.1.255
   etc.

So armed with this knowledge:

- 1000 divided by 256 (0 - 255 addresses) = 3 (*number for third octlet so 10.10.3.XXX*)
- 256 * 3 = 768 *(we get 768 address from the first three iterations)* subtract 1 = 767 *(the first address 10.10.3.0 is used as the subnet address and cannot be assigned to a host)*
- 1000 - 767 = 233 *(so we need 233 from the last iteration)* gives us **10.0.3.233**

Answer in CIDR notation = 10.10.3.233/16 *(the 1000th IP address that a host can be assigned)*

Answer (score 0):

by seeing subnet itself we can make out the first address of the subnet is 10.10.0.1 to 10.10.255.255.

since the mask is /16 last two octet can change and each octet can have value from 0-255 i.e., 256 possibility.

so if I want to find the 1000th ip ,then 
fourth octet = 1000%256(remainder)

third octet = 100/256(quotient)

in our case,
fourth octet = 253

third octet = 3

so 100th will be "10.10.3.232".

correct me if i'm wrong.Thanks